# Error when generating apk by eas expo with the "react-native-google-signin/google-signin" library

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin, eas

I have a question here: I'm using the "react-native-google-signin/google-signin" library to sign in with Google on my Android App. The problem is that this library requires a configuration in the android folder generated by the prebuild and when generating the apk through eas build, an error occurs because the servers must not be doing manual in the android folder as it is in my location. How can I resolve this? Could running eas build locally solve the problem? I didn't understand anything about config plugin

I tried running the command to generate an apk:

```
eas build -p android --profile preview"
```

I expected social login to occur normally

APK is generated but without social login functionality